# Referencing a variable with 'composite' name

Tags: r

I have a data frame in the form:

```
Idx Var X12 X34 
12 NA 444 100 
34 NA 500 777 
12 300 600 900
```

I need to replace the NAs in Var with a proper value referenced by 'Idx' in the 'X' variables, so if Idx=12 then we need the value of 'X12'. The resulting data frame will look like:

```
Idx Var X12 X34
12 444 444 100 
34 777 500 777 
12 300 600 900
```

I tried concating the 'Idx' with 'X' but R doesnt recognize this a a valid variable. What I tried:

```
df$Var <- ifelse(is.na(df$Var), 
   df[[paste0("X", df$Idx)]],
   df$Var
```

But this gives me an error:

```
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

Comment: For something like this you would normally reshape your data into “long” (or “tidy”) format. It makes the resulting code much easier to understand. Check out the packages ‹tidyr› and ‹dplyr›.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution where I iterate over each row and ask if `Var` is NA. If `Var` is NA I extract corresponding `Idx` column, else return `Var`.

```
d$Var <- apply(d, 1, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x[2]),
                                        x[paste0("X", x[1])],
                                        x[2]))
```

Comment: Thanks! most R-ish solution so far.

Comment: @Liord Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datatable` and `eval` for this

```
d <- data.table(read.table(text = "Idx Var X12 X34 
12 NA 444 100 
34 NA 500 777 
12 300 600 900", header = T))

d[is.na(Var), Var:= eval(parse(text = paste("X", Idx, sep = ""))), by = Idx]
d

    Idx Var X12 X34
1:  12 444 444 100
2:  34 777 500 777
3:  12 300 600 900
```

Comment: Thanks! lightning fast as usual with data.table. Note to myself: learn (somewhat cryptic) dt asap.

Comment: Liord, can you please upvote this answer if you found it useful

Comment: Tried to upvote this answer and the answer by PoGibas, However since I have less than 15 reputation the system said it will not register it yet. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a row/column indexing.  Get the index of NA elements of 'Var' column ('i1'), Then, with `match`, we find the column index, `cbind`it with the row index, and assign the values to the places occupied by NA

```
i1 <- is.na(df$Var) 
df$Var[i1] <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), match(paste0("X", df$Idx), names(df)[3:4])+2)][i1]
df
#   Idx Var X12 X34
#1  12 444 444 100
#2  34 777 500 777
#3  12 300 600 900
```